# Find My app doesn't find my AirTags if they are far from me but only under one MacBook Pro account

Tags: macos, ventura, find-my, airtag

I have a few AirTags. They show up fine on my iPhone and iPad but on my MacBook Pro M2 they say the old location of the last time they were near my MacBook Pro, even though an iPad sitting next to it will show their current location.

I spent a few hours on the phone and chat with Apple support and as one of the steps to try they had me create a new OS X user account on the Macbook Pro and log into the same iCloud account and that new account works fine. Apple support was never able to fix the issue, they went as far as to tell me the only way to find AirTags is to be close to them, which I know is wrong.

So what would cause `Find My` to not be able to find AirTags location when they aren't near? Shouldn't that information just be coming from iCloud? And why is it happening only on one OS X account?

Also, the other tabs of `Find My` work fine, it can get the location of any other device I have without issues regardless of where they are.

I'm on Ventura 13.3.1

Comment: Did they explain why the new account test was useful for troubleshooting where the source of the corruption / error was in your case?

Comment: Unfortunately Apple support doesn't seem to know much about AirTags and how they should work. They actually told me this is the normal way it should work and that the only way to find AirTags is to be near them. I explained that isn't true and that my other account can find them just fine regardless of where I'm at, at that point they escalated me and that person didn't know much either but their only new suggestion was to reinstall the OS in my Mac. I'm trying to avoid having to do that.

Comment: Aah - if it works correctly on the new user account, then it's clearly not a functional defect and an erase install is the correct fix. Then you can restore your backup and learn if the corruption was backed up or is cleared without risking loss of the data and files and apps and settings you may care about.

Comment: I was hoping to find a way to delete the `Find My` configuration or cache without having to reinstall.

Comment: that's a valid question - just may take a lot of reverse engineering - this site specializes in questions being open / unanswered for a decade or more and then getting an answer should someone discover the answer.